# MIMO (Multiple Input, Multiple Output) Block Diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on a control system project and need some help creating a block diagram using TikZ in LaTeX. I've attached an image of the block diagram I'm trying to recreate. As you can see, it includes a feedback loop with multiple inputs and outputs, and there are two matrices G(s) and C(s) that I need to represent within the blocks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum, node distance=4cm] (controller) {$C(s)= \begin{bmatrix}     c_{11}(s) & c_{12}(s) & \cdots & c_{1n}(s) \\ c_{21}(s) & c_{22}(s) & \cdots & c_{2n}(s) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ c_{n1}(s) & c_{n2}(s) & \cdots & c_{nn}(s) \end{bmatrix}$};
    \node [block, right of=controller, node distance=7cm] (system) {$G(s)= \begin{bmatrix} g_{11}(s) & g_{12}(s) & \cdots & g_{1n}(s) \\ g_{21}(s) & g_{22}(s) & \cdots & g_{2n}(s) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ g_{n1}(s) & g_{n2}(s) & \cdots & g_{nn}(s) \end{bmatrix}$};

    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system, node distance=5cm] (output) {};
    \coordinate [below of=u] (measurements) {};

    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);

    \draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);

    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is my try with just one-inout, one-output:
[image]

But I want like the following image, i want Multiple Input, Multiple Outpu Block Diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of tikz's specialties is drawing repeated things, here is an implementation with some other nesting options and style definitions, there are several ways to do one thing or another.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Tikz picture environment CFG
        >=latex',
        %Styles
        block/.style={
            draw,
            fill=white,
            rectangle, 
            minimum height=3em,
            minimum width=6em
        },
        sum/.style={
            draw,
            circle,
            fill=white,
            minimum size=2em,
            scale=0.75,
            transform shape,
            label={[label distance=-1.25em,scale=0.7]180:+},
            label={[label distance=-1em,scale=1]-90:-}
        }
    ]
    %Define some variables to reuse.
    \def\Xdist{1cm}
    \def\Ydist{1cm}
    \def\Controller{
        $C(s)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c_{11}(s) & c_{12}(s) & \cdots & c_{1n}(s) \\
            c_{21}(s) & c_{22}(s) & \cdots & c_{2n}(s) \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            c_{n1}(s) & c_{n2}(s) & \cdots & c_{nn}(s)
        \end{bmatrix}
        $
    }
    \def\System{
        $G(s)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
            g_{11}(s) & g_{12}(s) & \cdots & g_{1n}(s) \\
            g_{21}(s) & g_{22}(s) & \cdots & g_{2n}(s) \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            g_{n1}(s) & g_{n2}(s) & \cdots & g_{nn}(s)
        \end{bmatrix}
        $
    }
    %Starting to draw the thing.
    %\node[node style, position= distance of node_id](node_id) at (cartesian_or_polar_coordinate){node_content}; %Another of standard node definitions
    %\node[node style, position= distance of node_id](node_id){node_content}; %using positioning
    \node [block] (CTRL) at (0,0) {\Controller};
    \node [block, right=\Xdist of CTRL] (SYS) {\System};
    %Put some sum nodes
    \node [sum](S1) at ($(CTRL.180)+(-\Xdist,\Ydist*0.75)$){}; % $(CTRL.180)+(-\Xdist,\Ydist*0.75)$ by calc library
    \node [sum](S2) at ($(CTRL.180)+(-\Xdist*2,\Ydist*0.25)$){};
    \node [rotate=30](S3) at ($(CTRL.180)+(-\Xdist*3,-\Ydist*0.25)$){$\dots$};
    \node [sum](Sn) at ($(CTRL.180)+(-\Xdist*4,-\Ydist*0.75)$){};
    \node [left=\Xdist*4.5 of S1.center](IN){};
    \node [](OUT) at ($(S1-|SYS.0)+(\Xdist*2.5,0)$){}; 
    %Drawing arrows with some nodes and labels
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 0]in {1,2,\dots,n}{% Special condition drawing when \j counter is equial to 2
        \ifnum \j=2{
            \draw(S3-|IN) node[rotate=90] {\i};
            \draw(S3-|OUT) node[rotate=90] {\i};
            \draw(S3-|CTRL.0)++(1.5em,0.5em) node[rotate=90](temp) {\i};
            \draw(S3-|SYS.0)++(1em+\Xdist*0.4*\j,0) node[rotate=135] (temp2) {\i};
            \path(temp2)--++(0,-\Ydist*2.5) coordinate (temp3) (temp3-|temp)node[rotate=90]{\i};

        }
        \else{
            \draw[<-](S\i) -- (S\i-|IN) node[label={[label distance=1em,yshift=-0.4em]3:$r_\i$},anchor=0](IN-1){$Input_\i$};
            \draw[->](S\i) -- (S\i-|CTRL.180)node[label={[label distance=0.1em,yshift=-0.2em]175:$e_\i$},anchor=180](){};
            \draw[->](S\i-|CTRL.0)node[label={[label distance=\Xdist*0.2,yshift=-0.2em]5:$u_\i$},anchor=0](){} -- (S\i-|SYS.180);
            \draw[->](S\i-|SYS.0) -- (S\i-|OUT)node[label={[label distance=\Xdist*0.2,yshift=-0.3em]175:$y_\i$},anchor=180](OUT-1){$Output_\i$};
            \draw(S\i-|SYS.0)++(1em+\Xdist*0.4*\j,0)
                to [short,*-] ++ (0,-\Ydist*2.5) -| (S\i);
        }
        \fi
    }       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be interpreting your signals (and lines) as vectors, and, if needed, to interpret the sum-block as a vector component made from duplicates.

If you want to add that to this drawing, which is quite nice BTW, here's a way to do it. Besides that I only cleaned up your code to understand more easily what's going on.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\Cs[0]{$C(s)= \begin{bmatrix}%
                c_{11}(s) & c_{12}(s) & \cdots & c_{1n}(s) \\%
                c_{21}(s) & c_{22}(s) & \cdots & c_{2n}(s) \\%
                \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\%
                c_{n1}(s) & c_{n2}(s) & \cdots & c_{nn}(s) \end{bmatrix}$}

\newcommand\Gs[0]{$G(s)= \begin{bmatrix}%
                g_{11}(s) & g_{12}(s) & \cdots & g_{1n}(s) \\%
                g_{21}(s) & g_{22}(s) & \cdots & g_{2n}(s) \\%
                \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\%
                g_{n1}(s) & g_{n2}(s) & \cdots & g_{nn}(s) \end{bmatrix}$}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block}    = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
                        minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum}      = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input}    = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output}   = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    auto, 
    node distance=2cm,
    >=latex',
    lgnd/.style={anchor=north west,align=left},
]
    % ~~~ blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [input]                                          (input)      {};
    \node [sum,    right of=input]                         (sum)        {};
    \node [block,  right of=sum,        node distance=4cm] (controller) {\Cs{}};
    \node [block,  right of=controller, node distance=7cm] (system)     {\Gs{}};
    \node [output, right of=system,     node distance=5cm] (output)     {};

    % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \coordinate [below of=u] (measurements); % !!! this is not a node ... % {};

    \draw [->] (input)        -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum)          -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system)       -- node (y)   {$y$}           (output);

    \draw [-] (y)            |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node [near end] {$y_m$}    (sum);

    % ~~~ legend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[lgnd] at ([yshift=-26mm]input) {
        $r = (r_1, \dots r_n)$\\
        $sum = (sum_1,\dots sum_n)$ // vector component\\
        $e = (e_1, \dots e_n)$\\
        $y_m = (y_{m1}, \dots y_{mn})$\\
    };
    
    \node[lgnd] at ([yshift=-26mm]u) {
        $u = (u_1, \dots u_n)$\\
        $y = (y_1, \dots y_n)$\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```